# How to populate infinite scroll with images from 1 directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div id="content" class="clearfix"></div>`  which self populates with a list of image urls from a separate directory on my server.

Here is the live URL for the site : http://ilovesmallies.com/forum/showcase.php

I want to use infinite scroll and masonry plugins in this div.

However, I'm unsure of how to point towards a list of image urls with this script...

Here is how it is coded now and does not work.

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#content');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: 250
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#content',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#content a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you render all your images?

My favorite way is first paginating the image items, then apply:

itemSelector <---> class of each item. (in your case, it can be each image)

navSelector <---> id of pagination element

nextSelector <---> point to element (link to next page) in pagination

And I just make the pagination display none.

Comment: What do you mean render all my images?

is there anyway you can give an example code of how to paginate a div?

How do you make he pagination display none?